# How to properly keep a local reference to a child CCNode in a custom class in ARC

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting, retain-cycle

So, I want to hold a local reference to a child `CCNode` in a `CCNode` custom class without creating a retain cycle or without having the compiler complaining that the property or instance variable may be unpredictable set to `nil`

For instance with this custom class

```
@interface MyNode : CCNode
@property (nonatomic, strong) CCNode *background;
+ (id)nodeWithBackground:(id)background;
@end

@implementation MyNode

+ (id)nodeWithBackground:(id)background {
    MyNode *node = [MyNode node];
    node.background = background;
    node.background.scale = 0.01;//(*)
    return node;
}

- (void)setBackground:(CCNode *)background {
    if (_background) {//(*)
        [self removeChild:_background];
    }
    if (background) {
        [self addChild:background];
    }
    _background = background;
}

@end
```

...I have a retain cycle creating a node like this

```
CCSprite *background = [CCSprite ...];
MyNode *node = [MyNode nodeWithBackground:background];
[self addChild:node];
```

where `background` and `node` are never freed from memory when the scene is replaced

Changing the property `background` to weak causes the compiler to complain in the lines with  star (*) in the code above saying that the weak property or instance variable may be unpredictable set to `nil`

**Update:**

This is another approach with a weak instance variable and the settler and getter methods, the local strong variable (*) is because if the method uses the weak ivar `_background` the compiler complains saying that it may be unpredictable set to nil.

```
@interface MyNode : CCNode {
    __weak CCNode *_background;
}
+ (id)nodeWithBackground:(id)background;
- (void)setBackground:(CCNode *)background;
- (CCNode *)background;
@end

@implementation MyNode

+ (id)nodeWithBackground:(id)background {
    MyNode *node = [MyNode node];
    node.background = background;
    node.background.scale = 0.01;
    return node;
}

- (void)setBackground:(CCNode *)background {
    __strong CCNode *localRef = _background; //(*)
    if (localRef) {
        [self removeChild:localRef];
    }
    if (background) {
        [self addChild:background];
    }
    _background = background;
}

- (CCNode *)background {
    return _background;
}
@end
```

Is this approach a good thing to do in this case?

Comment: perhaps try not overriding the property setter (ie rename to applyBackground:), and creating a node that takes another node as input is kind of awkward, instead create and return the node, then run the applyBackground method because you already have that you don't need two methods to take the background as input.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I'd prefer to use a custom class to do the initialization and to set some properties or ivars to use with other helper methods, like running a bunch of actions in one child node calling a method like `[myNode runBackgroundTransition]`. Anyway, I've updated the question with another approach using only the weak ivar... thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: Yes but in this case, just return the node. Since you will be calling the setBackground: method any time at runtime it makes no difference if you call it right after creating the node from the caller as well.